# How to get Android system uptime and realtime from command line?

Tags: android, adb, system-clock

I'm writing a script containing several "adb shell" command. I also want to record the time when program execute these command in a form of realtime and uptime. I know I can get uptime and realtime through SystemClock:

```
SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
```

Is there any way I can get these information from the command line?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes. I mean adb shell command. I thought there might be some command that can inquire about system status. I know adb shell sysdump gfxinfo will return the uptime and realtime at the end of its output. What I want is a cleaner one.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try:

```
adb shell cat /proc/uptime
```

Comment: Thanks! Diego. The second number matches `SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()`. One small problem is that the numbers in `uptime` file is recorded in seconds with two decimal places. It seems that `SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()` is more accurate because it uses milliseconds.

Comment: Is there a way to get use it on a specific device when several are connected to the machine? (error: more than one device and emulator)

Answer (score 11):

If you only need to-the-second accuracy, `adb shell uptime` will also work.  Example output:

```plaintext
up time: 00:09:26, idle time: 00:07:15, sleep time: 00:00:00
```